# LuaInterface not calling a method

Tags: c#, .net, lua, luainterface

I'm trying to implement lua scripting in my C#.NET program, but when I execute the code, one of the methods is not been executed.

Here is the class:

```
namespace Program1
{
    public class LuaFunctions
    {
        Client Client { get; set; }
        private Lua lua { get; set; }

        public LuaFunctions(Client c) {
            this.Client = c;
            this.lua = new Lua();

            registerFunctions();
        }

        public void ExecuteCode(string code)
        {
            this.lua.DoString(code);
        }

        private void registerFunctions()
        {
            lua.RegisterFunction("message", this, this.GetType().GetMethod("Message"));
            lua.RegisterFunction("pname", this, this.GetType().GetMethod("playername"));
        }

        public void Message(string s)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s);
        }

        public string playername()
        {
            return Client.Player.Name;
        }
   }
}
```

When I execute this line of lua code "message(pname)" it does not even try to execute the method "playername()" to return some value, so it crashs in the DoString() line because "pname" is "returning" null.

Comment: If you are trying to call a `pname` function then you need `message(pname())`. `message(pname)` is is going to use `pname` the *function* as the value to the `message` function.

Comment: You're right, I was trying to create like some "custom variables" to use, like $name, so I would be able to use like, if($name == "Kyore") then, so you know how is possible to do that?

Comment: If you are trying to have the variable automatically update/etc. you'd have to see if LuaInterface supports that. If you just want to be able to set the variable then you just need to set a global or local/environment variable before calling the code that wants to use it. Instead of registering a function.

Answer (score 0):

`pname` is being registered as a function not set as a variable containing a string value.

When `message(pname)` is executed the `message` function is being given the value of the `pname` function instead of being given a string (or the result of *calling* the `pname`) function.

To pass the result of the `pname` function to `message` you would need to use `message(pname())`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, do you know how to create a variable instead a function to return a value?

Comment: @Kyore I don't. There should be a way to create a global that should be easy enough to find though (I would think). That being said isn't LuaInterface "on hold" at the moment? The github page seems to suggest using `NLua` instead it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where exactly you are trying to create the variable. If you are trying to set some variable in Lua, then `lua["somevariable"] = "value";` would work.  A more complete example could be:

Passing raw values to the state:

```
double val = 12.0;
lua["x"] = val; // Create a global value 'x' 
var res = lua.DoString ("return 10 + x*(5 + 2)")[0] as double;
```

Retrieving global values:

```
lua.DoString ("y = 10 + x*(5 + 2)");
var y = lua["y"] as double; // Retrieve the value of y
```